# backbone.js subview not shown on initial render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view:

```
App.Views.Rebill = App.Views.baseView.extend({
    view: 'requests._rebill_line',
    tag: 'div',
    className: 'row row-spaced',

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        App.get_view(self.view).done(function(data){
            var view = Mustache.render(data, {
                text: self.model.get('text'),
                cost: self.model.get('cost')
            });

            self.$el.append(view);

            var $selectVat = self.$el.find('select[name="vat"]');
            var vatPicker = new App.Views.VatPicker({
                model: self.model,
                el: $selectVat
            });
            vatPicker.render();
        });
        return self;
    }
});
```

this view is created in the parent:

```
addRebillLine: function(rebillModel){
    var self = this;
    var rebillView = new App.Views.Rebill({
        model: rebillModel
    });
    self.$el.after(rebillView.render().$el);
},
```

I have linked this to a button, which creates an empty model, and calls the `addRebillLine` function. This works fine, the new Rebill view appears in the DOM when I click the button.

However, on rendering the parent view, I run through a json array, create a model with each line, and call the `addRebillLine` function with that model. This runs, but the Rebill views are not added to the DOM.

Further up, the parent view is itself a child view, and is attached to its parent like so:

```
this.$el.find('[data-role="repair-items"]').append(itemView.render().$el);
```

The parent and grandparent views are rendered synchronously, and the child view asynchronously (App.get_view() is basically a call to $.ajax, hence the .done())

The wierd thing is that I do the same thing with the App.Views.VatPicker view, in several other places, and that works just fine. The only difference is that I pass an element to attach to into the VatPicker view. But if I pass the parent `$el` element in, and run `this.$parent.after(self.$el)` in my `done()` callback, that doesn't work either.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a callback which is called by the done() function and adds the child $el to the parent $el. But I still do not understand why the above code does not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this line:

```
this.$el.find('[data-role="repair-items"]').append(itemView.render().$el);
```

it assumes your render code is synchronous (as it should be) , but you render code is not.
When render return the $el is not set yet, this is a problem in your design.

You should solve this design issue by making your templates available when the view needs them. Don't invent the wheel here, take a look at the TodoMVC backbone example.

If you want your templates to be loaded aysnc, use requirejs.